# I/O with an array list

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I was just wondering if there is a way to loop through a text file until a particular string is found. 
For example, say you have a text file with the following in it:

banana

apple

grapes

melon

orange

cherries

strawberry chocolate vanilla

I basically want to write a program that loops through the input file until it gets to a particular string the user specifies and then stores the next line in an array list. So, basically say if I imputed cherries I want it to store strawberry, chocolate, vanilla in an array list. For the life of me I cannot figure out how to do this though, so anything would be appreciated. What I have so far is below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String line;
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the input file: ");
        String input = in.next();
        FileReader file = new FileReader(input);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

        System.out.print("What fruit do you want: ");
        String fruit = in.next();
        line = reader.readLine();


        while ((line != null)) {
            if(line.equals(fruit){
          }
            }
```

Comment: find the index of the *inputted term*, add `1` to it to get the required index.

Comment: So, are you basically saying to store everything in the input file in an array and then find the index of the imputed term as it appears in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the input until the searched line is encountered and store every line found afterwards in the list.

```
    String line;

    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        if(line.equals(fruit))
            break;

    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        lines.add(line);
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @bacon9 glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question correctly, I have an idea that you can start from

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) { // read the entire file into list but it consumes time especially if the file is big (not perfect choice)
  list.add(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

now what you can do

```
// add boolean to announce the occurrance of the word
boolean found = false;
for(String word: list){ // then you have a greater control over it to search
    if(word.equals(fruit)){
       found = true;
    }
    if (found) {
        // start taking the rest of the array into a new array or whatever you want to do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `boolean` to indicate when the value is found and when it is true you can add the line in the List :

```
 boolean isFound = false;
 String line;
 while ((line=reader.readLine())!= null) {
       if(!isFound && line.equals(fruit){
         isFound = true;
       }
       else if (isFound){
         names.add(line);
       }
 }
```

Comment: This will only work if the words in the file are unique. If the searched word gets repeated your code will drop the second string that should be part of the output.

Comment: It was intentional. I thought that it was expected. Idiot guesswork from my part.

Comment: Im not sure about it either. I just wanted to point it out. Shouldve been clarified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Create flag isFound. Set it to true when you find the string.
It will then process on the next loop and set to false like so.

```
bool isFound=false;       
while ((line != null)) {
          if(isFound==true){
              names.add(string)
              isFound=false;
          }
            if(line.equals(fruit){
              isFound=true;
          }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

check it out:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String line;
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the input file: ");
    String input = in.next();
    FileReader file = new FileReader(input);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

    System.out.print("What fruit do you want: ");
    String fruit = in.next();

    boolean found=false;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        if (line.equals(fruit) || found) {
            names.add(line);
            found=true;
        }
    }
}
```